# After installing a module, it still says my module isn't installed

Tags: python, terminal, installation, pip, fuzzy-search

I will attach a screenshot of my terminal, please can you explain what I'm doing incorrectly? Sorry if this is a stupid question, it seems very unobvious to me. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pip` is `pip2`.
You installed library for python2, and try to use it from python3.
The installation path is like `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fuzzywuzzy/fuzz.py` and python3 does not look here.

`pip3 install <libraryname>` will resolve this issue.